# what about firebase disk persistence mean?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If my android one to one chat app has 3 users A ,B, C.

When A send message to B.

C will not save this message data to disk?

In fact, C cannot see the message between A and B

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

**Meaning 1**: save all data in the database to disk?

or
**Meaning 2**: Only I have browsed?

Comment: if database has 100 messages and 90 messages was A send to B,will C save 100 message data to C's disk?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have misunderstood `setPersistenceEnabled`. This is the caching mechanism used by firebase. If you have enabled this option, if your app is offline then firebase caches your previously loaded data locally and displays it to you. When the network is back it synchs.

Below is the detailed description of how its works,

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities

Comment: yes i  want to ask its only catches previously loaded data or not?

Comment: Only the one which loaded previously.. @osas